# Rails routes: resourcing from the root path "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a Query resource that I want to route to the root of my domain. (So posting to "/" goes to the `queries#create` action, etc...).

My routes.rb:

```
root :to => "home#index"
resources :queries, :path => ''
```

rake routes:

```
           root        /                                           home#index
        queries GET    /                                           queries#index
                POST   /                                           queries#create
```

All seems fine, but when I try to post to "/", it is somehow getting routed to the 'root_path', even though I'm submitting it via `POST`. So instead of creating a new Query item, it just reloads the home page. I get this in the log:

```
Started POST "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-16 20:34:58 -0400
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

## Edit

When I move `:root =>` to the very bottom of the controller, I get a redirect loop when I `GET "/"`, which is why my ':root' definition isn't at the bottom.

## Edit

It works when I replace the :root definition with `get "/" => "home#index", :as => "root"`, but that feels too hackish to me. How do I specify what HTTP verbs to use on the `root` definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

`get "/" => "home#index", :as => "root"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the :url => {:action = "create"} or the method in your form_for?

Comment: Yes, it's a regular form, and it worked fine when queries were resources normally.

Comment: You're doing it right, you should specify the controller and the action you would want to set as the web application root. If you have anymore questions I'd reference [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)