# POST / GET not working correctly with Ruby on Rails Root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im using RoR to write my website and i've run into this issue with routes.

My routes file looks as such

```
  root to: "static#index"

  match '/index', to: 'static#index', via: [:get, :post]
  match '/download', to: 'static#download', via: [:get, :post]
  match '/terms', to: 'static#terms', via: 'get'
  match '/privacy', to: 'static#privacy', via: 'get'
  match '/jobs', to: 'static#jobs', via: 'get'
  match '/android', to: 'static#android', via: [:get, :post]
  match '/apply', to: 'static#apply', via: 'get'
  match '/faq', to: 'static#faq', via: 'get'
```

When I preform a GET request to https://www.website.com/ the page gets displayed.

However when I preform a POST request to the same address it returns a 404 page not found.

I do not have a index.html in my public directory.

So why is this POST request returning a 404 when it is matched to both GET and POST and the GET works correctly?

EDIT

i've added this line

```
match '/', to: 'static#index', via: [:get, :post]
```

just below my root to declaration, however now my page shows a 422 error instead of a 404

Comment: Can you post contents of your log after you make the post request?

Comment: You probably want a ':' after the 'to'. It's a hash.

Comment: Sorry that was a type kdeisz, i've fixed it in the question

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root says "The `root` route only routes `GET` requests to the action.". @lcguida's answer below worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root URL is the one that handles https://www.website.com/ from your example. When you specify

```
root to: "static#index"
```

You have declared a GET route for /, which maps to StaticController#index. The POST request that you are making to https://www.website.com/ is not handled by the root route, thus properly returns a 404.

I'm guessing that you want the POST request to go to either /index, /download or /android. You need to specify the endpoint fully in the URL in order for the request to be routed properly.

Comment: Ok, but is there anyway to do a POST route for / ? other than using like https://www.website.com/index

Comment: @zoruc Why do yout want to do a POST to the index page?

Comment: @rockskull when im using the facebook canvas page and its trying to load my site it just returns 404 or now 422 since it is a post request to the site I believe

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
post '/' => "static#index", as: "root"
```

[Rails routes: resourcing from the root path "/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183585/rails-routes-resourcing-from-the-root-path)

Answer (score 1):

My preference and I think the cleanest implementation would be:

```
resources :static, :only => [:index, :create], :path => "/"
```